# Reinitialise code that fires on keyup event when user's click on a div?

Tags: jquery

I have a list which is filtered as you type into an input. Below is the javascript responsable:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    $(".filtered:first li").each(function () {    
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).addClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden");
            count++;
        }
    });
    $('.li-group').each(function(){
        if($(this).children(':visible').length == 0) {
           $(this).prev().addClass('hidden');
        }
        else {
            $(this).prev().removeClass('hidden');
        }
    }); 
});
```

I want to have an close 'button' which empties the input of all text when you click it. Ive done this with the code below. However as the code above fires on the keyup event, it isn't reinitialised so the hidden results arn't shown. Thanks

```
$('#filter-close').click(function(){
        $('input#filter').val('');
});
```

Comment: `input#filter` seems *too specific* for me, so unless you have a reason to do it, `#filter` is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution is:

```
$('#filter-close').click(function(){
    $('input#filter').val('');
    $("#filter").keyup();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should call its `keyup` handlers manually. So first you set the empty value, then call the handlers which will act based on the new value:

```
$('#filter-close').click(function(){
        $('input#filter').val('').keyup();
});
```

This is a shortcut syntax for [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)ing the `keyup` event:

```
$('#filter-close').click(function(){
        $('input#filter').val('').trigger('keyup');
});
```

If you have other `keyup` event handlers on the input box that you don't want to run (simple triggering will run all of them), you can give your event a [namespace](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) (use `bind()` instead of `on()` for jQuery older than 1.7).

```
$("#filter").on('keyup.doSearch', function () {
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    /* the rest of your keyup handler code */
});
```

and then you can trigger it like this:

```
$('#filter-close').click(function(){
        $('input#filter').val('').trigger('keyup.doSearch');
});
```

Comment: ouch, just 9 seconds earlier! :)

Comment: @themarcuz Seems like my answer was too long for the OP :)

Comment: @themarcuz I'd upvote yours also if you did not query the DOM twice.